# Facebook Graph API friends' names and ids

Tags: javascript, json, api, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I know that if I simply try to get a list of my friends, it will only return **app friends** AKA friends who **also** have given permissions to Facebook

So, rightfully so, when I do a GET **'me/friends'**, I only see 5 friends.

However, when I do a GET **me/posts/?fields=likes.fields(name)**, it obviously returns data with a list of friends who have liked my posts:

```
{
  "id": "post1id",
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "id": "id1"
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "id": "id2"
      }....
    ]
}
```

It shows **all** friends, so non-app and app friends.

My question is, if all I want to use is my friends' names and id's from this result, would it be allowed, considering that some of these friends are not app-friends?

Comment: I don't understand how this would help you in any way... Can you elaborate? I doubt that ALL friends will like one of your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work the API with the user token, you may receive all likes (including friends who don't use the app, non-friends, friends who use the app, pages) but this is at all no indication for a users friends. Anyways you can utilize ALL data provided by the GraphAPI as long as you don't work around the limitations with something like exploiting the game invite feature.